# Tkinter variable value is not passed to other class

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a little bit of strange problem and I will try to explain.

So I am trying to connect to WiFi through tkinter, and I am passing variables like name of the WiFi and the password, between classes, and its working. I know this because I am displaying them in Labels, but when I try to connect to WiFi, the variables are not passed as arguments to the connection string.

Here is part of my code :

```
 import tkinter as tk
 from PIL import Image, ImageTk
 import time
 import os
 from wifi import Cell, Scheme
 LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 12)


 from tkinter import END




class SeaofBTCapp(tk.Tk):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    container = tk.Frame(self)
    self.geometry("480x800")
    self.label = tk.Label(text="This is the start page",background="blue",height=2)
    self.label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=0)
    self.time1 = ''
    self.time2 = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    self.watch = tk.Label(self, text=self.time2, font=('times', 12, 'bold'))
    self.watch.pack()
    self.changeLabel() #first call it manually

    
    self.a=tk.StringVar()  
    self.passcode=tk.StringVar()





    container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

    container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=100)
    container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    self.frames = {}

    for F in (SetUpPage,ChoseWIFI,TypePassword,Connecting):
        frame = F(container, self)

        self.frames[F] = frame

        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

    self.show_frame(SetUpPage)

def show_frame(self, cont):
    frame = self.frames[cont]
    frame.tkraise()

def changeLabel(self):
    self.time2 = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    self.watch.configure(text=self.time2)
    self.after(200, self.changeLabel)  # it'll call itself continuously











class SetUpPage(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    image = Image.open("wifi_icon.gif")
    image = image.resize((50, 50), Image.ANTIALIAS)

    self.reset_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

    image1 = Image.open("ethernet_icon.gif")
    image1 = image1.resize((50, 50), Image.ANTIALIAS)

    self.reset_img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1)
    self.but = tk.Button(self, text="WORK IN", height=180, width=180, image=self.reset_img,command=lambda: controller.show_frame(ChoseWIFI)).place(x=150, y=125)
    self.but1 = tk.Button(self, text="WORK OUT", height=180, width=180, image=self.reset_img1).place(x=150, y=425)

class ChoseWIFI(tk.Frame):



def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.controller=controller

    
    self.mylistbox=tk.Listbox(self,width=80,height=10,font=('times',13))
    self.mylistbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',self.CurSelet)
    self.mylistbox.place(x=100,y=190)
    self.wifiscan()
    self.but = tk.Button(self, text="CONNECT", height=10, width=10,command=lambda: controller.show_frame(TypePassword)).place(x=150, y=525)

    


    
def wifiscan(self):

   allSSID = [cell.ssid for cell in Cell.all('wlan0')]
   print (allSSID )# prints all available WIFI SSIDs
  



   for i in range(len(allSSID )):
        if print(str(allSSID [i]))== print(myssid):
            a = i
            print("hit")
            myssidA = allSSID [a]
            print( myssidA )
            break
        else:
            print ("getout")



   print (myssid)

   
   self.itemsforlistbox=allSSID
   
   for items in self.itemsforlistbox:
       self.mylistbox.insert(END,items)

def CurSelet(self,a):
    value=self.mylistbox.get(self.mylistbox.curselection())
   
    self.o=self.controller.a
    self.o.set(value)
    

    

    
class TypePassword(tk.Frame):



def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.controller=controller
    #self.entry1 = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.controller.shared_data["username"])
    #self.entry1.pack()
    
    self.L2 = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.controller.a)
    self.L2.pack()
    self.L1 = tk.Label(self, text="Type password")
    self.L1.pack()
    
    
    
    self.E1 = tk.Entry(self, bd=5)
    self.E1.place(x=150, y=325)
    #self.connect()
   
    
    
    self.but = tk.Button(self, text="CONNECT", height=10, width=10,command=lambda:[self.connect(), controller.show_frame(Connecting)]).place(x=150, y=525)
def connect(self):
    self.controller.passcode.set(self.E1.get())
    #os.system('nmcli d wifi connect "%s" password %s iface %s' % (self.controller.a,self.controller.passcode, self.controller.a)) # vive1234 is the password to my wifi myssidA is the wifi name 

        
    self.pas=self.controller.passcode
    self.passw = self.E1.get()
    
   
    self.pas.set(self.passw)
    

class Connecting(tk.Frame):



def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.controller=controller
    
    self.entry1 = tk.Label(self, text="CONNECTING.....")
    self.entry1.pack()
    
    self.entry2 = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.controller.a)
    self.entry2.pack()
    
    self.entry3 = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.controller.passcode)
    self.entry3.pack()
   
    
    self.but = tk.Button(self, text="CONNECT11", height=10, width=10,command=self.k).place(x=150, y=525)
    #self.but.tk.bind(('<but>', self.k))
     
def k(self):
    #connection string for WIFI
    os.system('nmcli d wifi connect "%s" password %s iface %s' % (self.controller.a,self.controller.passcode, self.controller.a)) # vi
    
    print("KKKK")

if __name__ == "__main__":

# Calls its attribute.

app = SeaofBTCapp()
a=app.changeLabel()

app.after(200,a )
# Calls its attribute.


app.mainloop()
```

Comment: `self.controller.a` and `self.controller.passcode` are `StringVar`, so need to use `get()` to get their content: `self.controller.a.get()` and `self.controller.passcode.get()`.

Comment: thank youu @acw1669 i completly missed that partt xD